# Не могу вывести значение из Объекта

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, dom, if

у меня есть Объект в котором имею енергию (power) так же есть функция которая прибавляэт значению енергии + 10 при нажатии на клавишу, все работает, но как мне вывести значение енергии и использовать в коде далее в других функциях, как мне взять power ( с уже измененным значением и использовать далее в других функциях ) 
прошу помочь, если можно не очень сложными способами, хочу понять для себя

```js
function text() {
  document.getElementById("elem").addEventListener("click", plusPower);
  let numberPowerCar = document.getElementById("numPower");
  let numberPowerCarTwo = document.getElementById("numPowertwo");


  let subjectCar = {
    subject: "car",
    power: 0,
    numpower: function(numplus) {
      this.power = this.power + numplus
    }
  }
  subjectCar.power(0);

  function plusPower() { //функция добавления енергии
    let numbr = 10;
    if (subjectCar.power <= 10000) {
      subjectCar.power = subjectCar.power + numbr;
      numberPowerCar.innerHTML = subjectCar.power;
      //  numberPowerCarTwo.innerHTML = subjectCar.power;  тут оно выводит, если я ету строку пропишу тут 

    }
  }
  numberPowerCarTwo.innerHTML = subjectCar.power; // вставляя тут оно не ввыводит, почему ?
}
text();
```

```html
<button id="elem">Добавить енергии</button>
<h5 id="numPower">значение power</h5>
<h5 id="numPowertwo">сюда я так же хочу выводить значение, но немогу</h5>*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что на строчке с ошибкой

```
 subjectCar.power(0);
```

выполнение кода прерывается.

Comment: если я удаляю эту строчку, мне вывод значение 0

Comment: @ike77 А сколько надо?

Comment: значение в зависимости сколько раз я нажал на клавишу, я не могу понять как мне использовать в дальнейшем уже измененное значение power

Comment: numberPowerCar.innerHTML = subjectCar.power;
ета строчка работает только если она в функции которая прибавляет по +10

Comment: но когда я ету же строчку пишу в любом другом месте то выводит значение 0

Comment: @ike77 Потому что эти строчки выполняются один раз - когда вызывается функция `text`.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gucaxib/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @ike77 Потому что эти строчки выполняются один раз - когда вызывается функция text. – Igor -----


я понимаю, но если удалить ету строчку с функции и вставить только после функции она не работает и не выводит мне innerHTML выше кинул ссылку

Comment: @ike77 Спасибо за ссылку, она не нужна - я сделал в Вашем вопросе работающий пример. Объясните, чего Вы хотите. В любом коде, которому нужно значение `subjectCar.power`, Вы можете его получить, вызвав `subjectCar.power`.